# Disable a div in a page Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this code HTML:

```
 <div id="top"></div>
                             <div id="mid" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="close">INCHIDE &nbsp; X</div>  
                                <p id="first_paragraph">
                                 TEXT
                                 </p>                           
 </div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
   #top {
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 38px;
    background: url(images/DESPRE-NOI.png) no-repeat;

}

 body.page-id-10#top {
   display:none;

}
```

I want to #top deactivation of the page in wordpress which has ID 10.

I tried but unfortunately does not work ... Can you tell me please what is wrong?

This is the site:

www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by deactivating?do you mean it won't be clicked? or viewed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to give you hooks (for JavaScript or CSS) on #top depending whether or not you are on the page with ID 10.

```
<?php
    if(is_page(10)) {
         <div id="top" class="top-inactive"></div>
    } else {
         <div id="top" class="top-active"></div>
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a child or descendant selector:

Child `body.page-id-10>#top`

Descendant `body.page-id-10 #top`